# put the output to the file when program crash during ruuning

Tags: gnome-terminal

I run c program. It is obvious that by <kbd>></kbd> . you can put the output to the file. But If my program has some error during running  and when I go to text file. I do not see any thing is there any way to put those printf to file (befor the program suppose those errors)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to redirect the error (STDERR) to the file along with the output(STDOUT). Just do the following:

```
Program &> filename
```

or

```
Program > filename 2&>1
```

If you want to append the file rather than overwriting:

```
Program &>> filename
```

or

```
Program >> filenmae 2&>1
```

The above will put the STDOUT and STDERR to the same file. In case you just want to put the STDERR to a different file, do the following:

```
Program 2> filename
```

to append the file

```
Program 2>> filename
```

Comment: thanks, But I do not see anything on filename. By the I run my program by sudo (if has any difference )

Comment: Sudo has nothing to do with it if sudoers is not modified beforehand. If you want to put the errors that would be printed on screen to a file then my answer is the way to do it. If its not answering your need could you please be more specific with your question?

Comment: I run my program is this way "sudo ns myfile &> output ". and ns is the name of my program. but no thing on output

Comment: myfile is an argument to the program, right? Did the original output being saved to the file?

Comment: sorry for delay, yes myfile is an argument and also when myfile has not error I see the result on "output". But this myfile (which I change it a bit ) during running has error and stop before ending . and when I go to the output I do not see the output. By when I run the program is this way "sudo ns myfile" I see the results on the terminal until the error

Comment: That means while you are running the program as Sudo the output is being shown on the terminal rather than being saved on the file. If this is the case then could you check your code to make sure its not messing with anything.